# Sharing a C# Console Application

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, console-application

I have written a console application in C# using .NET 3.1 in Visual Studio 2019. I want to share it with my friends so they can run it on their computers. Obviously, I don't want to force them to install any additional components.

I have already tried using the publish option in Visual Studio, but when run on another computer, the console immediately closes (running it through CMD shows an error, stating that .NET is missing on the computer). Is there any way I could share my application? I have invested a lot of time in it, and I would hate to just throw it away.

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: According to [.NET and .NET Core Lifecycle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core), .NET Core 3.1 is no longer supported.

Comment: Try to change the target framework of the console project to .net 6.0, or rebuild a console (.net framework), generate exe and send it to him

Answer (score 0):

As far as .net deployment, maybe WiX?

Alternatively it might (depends on your code) be very simple to convert it to a uwp console app. uwp is c# as well, and even shares almost all the .net libraries. Assuming your friends are running windows 10 or 11 it is extremely likely it will 'just work'.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps
Link to deploy UWP console app. All built right into visual studio...

On the bright side, if you make it UWP, it will work on literally almost any platform that microsoft owns. (XBOX, hololens, surfaces, desktops, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dotnet core application completely selfcontained (no need to install .net core).

Update your .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then

> dotnet publish -c Release"

makes you a single exe!

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/making-a-tiny-net-core-30-entirely-selfcontained-single-executable